# Help with understanding the big picture in a programming project

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Which Stack Exchange site is the best place to ask a question if I want help understanding the big picture of an algorithm in a C++ programming project?

Is [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) the best place to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code Review is definitely a wrong place to ask. Don't go there.

Since your question is not directly programming-related, there is little chance it's on-topic for Stack Overflow.

We have a site specific for computing science and algorithms, [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com). You can try asking there. Don't forget to read about [their scopes](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).